# remove specific element from a array in mongoDB (aggregation pipeline)

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongoDB, and I want to update an array. I'm using the aggregation pipeline.

With `{ $toInt: { $indexOfArray: ["$meta.users", "johndoe"] } }`, I get the index of "johndoe". The problem is: I cannot use `$slice` because this takes 2 or three arguments as starting point or as starting point + number to keep. But take this array:

```
["johndoe", "janedoe", "jamesdoe"]
```

How, with an aggregation pipeline, can I convert this array to **remove "janedoe" (index: 1)`` from the array, so after the aggregation pipeline, I want this:

```
["johndoe", "jamesdoe"]
```

My code sor far (does'nt work):

```
              $concatArrays: [
    // take everything BEFORE the element to splice
                  {
                    $slice: ["$meta.users", { $multiply: [-1, { $subtract: [{ $toInt: { $indexOfArray: ["$meta.users", "janedoe"] } }, 1] }] }, { $size: "$meta.users" }]
                  },
// take everything AFTER the element to splice
                  {
                    $slice: ["$meta.users", { $multiply: [1, { $add: [{ $toInt: { $indexOfArray: ["$meta.users", "janedoe"] } }, 1] }] }, { $size: "$meta.users" }]
                  }
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- this is a way to do it, we could do it with `$switch` also and 3 cases but this smaller query a bit.
- if `index<0 or index>array_size` doesn't change the array
- if there is before (index>0) finds the before else before = []
- after works ok with slice even if there is no after
- finally `(concatArrays before after)`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70624173-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":{"index":2}},
 {"$set":
  {"ar":
   {"$cond":
    [{"$or":
      [{"$lt":["$index", 0]}, {"$gte":["$index", {"$size":"$ar"}]}]},
     "$ar",
     {"$concatArrays":
      [{"$cond":
        [{"$gt":["$index", 0]}, {"$slice":["$ar", 0, "$index"]}, []]},
       {"$slice":
        ["$ar", {"$add":["$index", 1]}, {"$size":"$ar"}]}]}]}}},
 {"$unset":["index"]}])
```

Query2

- if you want to delete from an array based on value and not on index you can do this also to delete all values from the array

*if you want to delete only the first found value you can do it with `$reduce` instead of filter

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70624173-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"ar":{"$filter":{"input":"$ar", "cond":{"$ne":["$$this", "2"]}}}}}])
```